# Grails loading issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, grails

I have a table, build inside an  tag. The table is centered in the page, and every line have an image. What happens when the page load is the following:

a) The table inicially appear at the top-left side of the screen
b) because there are many values to fill in the table, the table is kind of blinking, and i can clearly see it being constructed.
c) once the table is all loaded, it returns to its right position, which is in the center.

My question is, it seems the page is displayed before everything is loaded. How can i make sure i only display the gsp when everything is loaded. Is there any way of doinf that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, set the table to be invisible with the css property `visibility:hidden` or `display:none`. Make the table display when the page is fully loaded using the following JQuery Javascript

```
$(function() {
 $('#mytable').show();
});
```

where `mytable` is the ID of the table.